# Redirect to respective parent directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Lets say i have two directories in root.

root/project1

root/project2

if anyone calls any files or directory of project1 (that is project1/folder1/file.txt) then it has to redirect to project1. same with project2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Redirect

```
RedirectMatch ^/(project1|project2)/.+$ /$1/
```